# Problems Accordion Panel Jquery 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I made fork of this codepen example of acordion

[Material design Accordion - Bootstrap v3](https://codepen.io/carlos91suazo/pen/zzVxqo)

I want to know why I have have the next error :

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

I need a solution because I'm using that version of Jquery in my project.

If I downgrade the version of Jquery to 2.1.3 version the example work correctly, but that is not a solution for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's likely the problem is in Boostrap. I suggest you search the Bootstrap forum for jQuery 3.x incompatibilities.

Comment: What does `data-parent="#"` supposed to do?  I removed this and the collapsing started working.  Looks like it is some sort of grouping mechanism around a selector.  Which `#` is not a valid selector.   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage